# Showcase the first n-items in a bootstrap grid

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, responsive

I work on a page with a responsive design utilising the bootstrap grid. According to specification I need to be able to showcase the first line in the grid with bigger images. Typically i want 3 images in the first row when the rest of the grid has four images in each row.

What I try to accomplish is best illustrated with the following image:
[image]

How can I make this work? Solutions with classes, css and javascript are all accepted as I control all the client code.

Comment: Bootstrap documentation pretty exhaustively describes this. Have you read it? Or maybe you've already tried to implement this and have a specific problem?

Comment: You're right. This should be easy. I don't know why I wasn't able to see the solution right away. But I found a solution. I will be posting it as an answer. Thanks for taking the time to read my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you started: http://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/BLrvAw

All the elements are in the same row so they can float as the grid changes, everything else uses standard bootstrap classes.

I should add that this works well when all your .col elements are the same height. All these bootstrap column elements are `float:left;` and if the heights vary then some of the divs may not float to the expected position. The fix is that you may have to apply some custom styling to selected column elements, e.g. `clear:left;`

Good luck!

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">1</div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">2</div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">3</div>

<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">4</div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">5</div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 hidden-xs">6</div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 hidden-xs">7</div>

<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 hidden-xs">8</div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 hidden-xs">9</div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 hidden-xs">10</div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 hidden-xs">11</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Same solution as I ended up with when I managed to turn my brain back on! I appreciate the contribution! :)

Comment: Thanks @Lars-PetterHansen, please note that I added another comment to my suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding the classes manually in the loop where I set the bootstrap column classes.

```
if(idx === 0){
    containerElem.append($('<span class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 game-wrapper"></span>').append(item));
} else if (idx === 1){
    containerElem.append($('<span class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 game-wrapper"></span>').append(item));
} else if (idx === 2) {
    containerElem.append($('<span class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4 game-wrapper"></span>').append(item));
} else{
    containerElem.append($('<span class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 game-wrapper"></span>').append(item));
}
```

So that the first item gets a "col-xs-12", the first and second items get a "col-sm-6" and the first three items get a "col-md-4".

Probably not the most elegant solutions, but at least it works.